# How do I animate two HTML elements using angular swapping in a flexbox without the elements snapping around when the switch happens?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, animation

This is a problem I have encountered time and time again, and I couldn't find anything useful about it. Let's say I have two divs and I want one to slide out while another comes in a takes it's place. Straight forward enough. The problem is when the swap happens both elements appear in the flexbox for a period making all the contents of the flexbox shift until the swap is over. How do I make the transition seamless?

Video of the current state of the animation: https://youtu.be/gVDmOpG_p9A

Angular animation code:

```
     animations: [
    trigger('flyInOut', [
      state('in', style({ opacity:1,transform: 'translateY(0)' })),
      transition('void => *', [
        style({ opacity:0,transform: 'translateY(100%)' }),
        animate('200ms')
      ]),
      transition('* => void', [
        animate(200, style({ opacity:0,transform: 'translateY(100%)' }))
      ])
    ]),
    trigger('fadeInOut', [
      state('in', style({ opacity:1,transform: 'translateY(0)' })),
      transition('void => *', [
        style({ opacity:0,transform: 'translateY(-100%)' }),
        animate('200ms 400ms')
      ]),
      transition('* => void', [
        animate(200, style({ opacity:0,transform: 'translateY(-100%)' }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="controls">
  <div
    [@fadeInOut]
    *ngIf="resultVisible"
    class="replacement-icon"
    width="200"
    height="200"
  >
    <p-button label="Next" (onClick)="nextThing()"></p-button>
  </div>
<div
  [@flyInOut]
  *ngIf="!resultVisible"
  class="button"
  #playButton
  onclick="this.classList.toggle('active')"
  (click)="toggleMusic()"
>
  <div class="bottom" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200"></div>
  <div class="icon" width="200" height="200">
    <div>
      <div
        class="middle left"
        x="0"
        y="0"
        width="200"
        height="200"
        fill="#fff"
      ></div>
      <div
        class="middle right"
        x="0"
        y="0"
        width="200"
        height="200"
        fill="#fff"
      ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pointer"></div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS code:

```
body {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
.button {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.bottom {
  background: #01bdd6;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
}
.button:active .bottom {
  background: #1578e9;
}
.icon {
  height: 200px;
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
  transition: transform 500ms;
  width: 200px;
}
.replacement-icon {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```